# Typescript - optional type predicate

Tags: typescript

I'm interested in building a type predicate function like this, which will return true when the number is a real number and simultaneously make the type stricter:

```js
function isRealNumber(input: number | undefined | null): input is number {
    return input !== undefined && input !== null && Number.isFinite(input);
}
```

However, this produces incorrect types in some circumstances when negated, e.g.:

```js
const myNumber: number | null = NaN as any;
if (isRealNumber(myNumber)) {
    const b = myNumber;  // b is number, correct
} else {
    const b = myNumber;  // b is `null`, should be `null | number`
}
```

This can be worked around using multiple statements in the conditional, but this is less ideal:

```js
function isRealNumber(input: number | undefined | null): boolean {
    return input !== undefined && input !== null && Number.isFinite(input);
}

const myNumber: number | null = NaN as any;
if (isRealNumber(myNumber) && myNumber !== null && myNumber !== undefined) {
    const b = myNumber;  // b is number, correct
} else {
    const b = myNumber;  // b is `null | number`, correct
}
```

Is there any way in typescript to have a single function which will correctly narrow the type without also producing incorrect types sometimes when negated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a "one-sided" or "fine-grained" [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#15048](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15048), but this is not currently directly supported in TypeScript.  The issue is open, but it's not clear that anything will happen here.

There is a workaround [mentioned](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15048#issuecomment-534376266) in that issue, though.  If you change your guarded type from `input is number` to `input is RealNumber` where `RealNumber` is some type assignable to but strictly narrower than `number`, then things will start working.

And while there is no actual distinction in the type system between `RealNumber` and `number`, you can "fake" one by using a technique called [branded primitives](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal).  That's where you take a primitive type like `number` and [intersect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) it with an object type containing a phantom "brand" or "tag" property.  For example:

```
function isRealNumber(input: number | undefined | null): input is number & { __realNumber?: true } {
    return input !== undefined && input !== null && Number.isFinite(input);
}

const myNumber: number | null = NaN as any;
if (isRealNumber(myNumber)) {
    const b = myNumber;  // b is number & {__realNumber?: true}
} else {
    const b = myNumber;  // b is number | null
}
```

That looks more reasonable.  If `isRealNumber(myNumber)` is `true`, then `b` is narrowed to `number & {__realNumber?: true}`.  That `{__realNumber?: true}` property isn't going to actually be there at runtime (it's a "phantom" property), but that shouldn't matter much, since `b` is still a `number`.  And when `isRealNumber(myNumber)` is `false`, then `b` is not narrowed at all.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgJQKYEMA2A5EAWwCMMAnAChjAAcQoAuRMI0sxAH0XABMNhqGHp2YgcOAJRNqdKMhSiS5RADJEAb0QB9LWWz5W5APxMoZEBkQBfDQChEDxHqggySGfUQBCALw-uYHwCYEKqah5yvv4s4mGIBEpkAHSoAGLUMFAYVLT0EgDctla2thAIKHKEAJ4JbEwsiSIxOIj+eFh4iFgKWGBVhTDAiFTo+rXkFNXjZBISdo6IZWAViMStiFOGZPkOAPS7q-KKbKoaOnq40yaIZhbFNhg4KJbq9o5LK2v+m4k7iPuHVDHZRcZpFWxAA)

Comment: Amazing, this was a huge help, thank you so much!